# For what pairs of numbers does the norm function fail as a Euclidean function in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{14}]$?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, euclidean-algorithm

(By "norm" here I mean "absolute value of the norm)"

Are their infinitely many such pairs or is it finite in the sense that its just a few primes that cause the problem (like in that other famous Euclidean but not norm-Euclidean domain)?

I've tried searching for these pairs by looking at numbers with small norms, but of course I know this is woefully inefficient. I think I've found one such pair: $\gcd(3, 3 + \sqrt{14})$. Then $1 \times 3 + \sqrt{14} = 3 + \sqrt{14}$ but $|N(\sqrt{14})| > N(3)$, and in general it seems like any rational multiple of $3$ will result in a remainder with a norm too large. Clearly I'm in need of some theoretical insight, such as perhaps with ideals.

Comment: You might have to offer a monetary award on this one, like Erdős used to do.

Comment: The classic Clarke paper says something about "admissible primes" maybe the "inadmissible primes" are the ones that make the problem fore norm-Euclidean?

Comment: These questions are resolved here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1856408/have-i-found-an-example-of-norm-euclidean-failure-in-mathbb-z-sqrt14/1865435#  In short, $(3,3+\sqrt{14})$ does not fail, but $(2, 1+\sqrt{14})$ should fail.