# Continued Fraction of $ \frac{7 + 2 \sqrt{2}}{9 + \;\,\sqrt{2}}$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$

Tags: number-theory, continued-fractions, euclidean-algorithm

We can read from various sources that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ has class number one, and that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ is a Euclidean domain.  However, it also has a group of units: $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]^\times =(1 + \sqrt{2})^\mathbb{Z}$.  Let's try an example:

- $79 = (9 \times 9) - 2 \times (1 \times 1) = (9 + \sqrt{2})\times(9 - \sqrt{2})$
- $41 = (7 \times 7) - 2 \times (2 \times 2) = (7 + 2 \sqrt{2})\times(7 - 2 \sqrt{2}) $

This is just a quick way to get two relatively prime numbers in the ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$. Can we get a continued fraction for the ratio of the two of them?

$$  \frac{7 + 2 \sqrt{2}}{9 + \;\,\sqrt{2}} = \frac{59}{79}+
\frac{25}{79}\sqrt{2}\in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$$

So now I have to qualify a bit what I mean by Eucliean algorithm.  The norm $N\big(a + b \sqrt{2}\big) = a^2 - 2b^2$.  Then I guess we have

$$ y = m x + b $$

with $m \in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ and $N(b) < N(x)$. And then we iterate the Euclidean algorithm until we obtain the GCD.  Hopefully that is right?

---

I guess we'd have to flip them:

$$ \frac{9 + 1 \times \sqrt{2}}{7 + 2 \times \sqrt{2}} = \frac{59}{41} + \frac{9}{41} \sqrt{2}  \approx 1 \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$$

This is a really crummy approimation.  Let's try a "subtractive"  Euclidean algorithm...

- $(9 + \sqrt{2}) - (7 + 2 \sqrt{2}) = 2 - \sqrt{2}  < 1 $ looks good.
- $(9 + \sqrt{2}) + (7 + 2 \sqrt{2}) = 16 + 3 \sqrt{2}$ Looks worse.  $16 \times 16 - 3 \times 2 \times 2 > 100 $.

And two other possibilities:

- $(9 + \sqrt{2}) - \sqrt{2} \times(7 + 2 \sqrt{2}) =  5 - 6 \sqrt{2}$
- $(9 + \sqrt{2}) + \sqrt{2} \times (7 + 2 \sqrt{2}) = 13 + 8 \sqrt{2}$

and I've started to conclude the quotient should be $m=1$.  The first step could read:

$$  9 + \sqrt{2} = 1 \times \big(7 + 2 \times \sqrt{2}\big) + \big( 2 - \sqrt{2}\big)$$

I have my doubts.  We could have chosen another basis $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}] = 1 \mathbb{Z}\oplus (\sqrt{2}-1)\mathbb{Z}$ as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module.

Comment: For a start, why not rationalize the denominator of $(7+2\sqrt 2)/(9+\sqrt 2)$  by multiplying its numerator and denominator by $9-\sqrt 2\;$?

Comment: Your concept looks correct - you should be able to just run the Euclidean algorithm to do it. (It's not immediately clear to me how you _find_ your $m$, mind you, but I think that's only a sign that I need coffee...)

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Right. what is the Euclidean algorithm here? one certainly exists. i don't think it's straightforward. just my opinion.

Comment: Did you look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2524792/gcd-of-two-elements-in-mathbb-z-left-frac1-sqrt-112-right (which is over in the 'related' column)? It suggests looking at an 'approximate' division of the two items, which in your case is $(9+\sqrt{2})/(7+2\sqrt{2})=59/41-(11/41)\sqrt{2}$ as a sort of guiding principle. More generally, the set of multiples of any number in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ forms a lattice and it shouldn't be too hard to find the 'closest' of those multiples to your target number (though the distance in question isn't exactly 'Euclidean' in the other sense).

Comment: math.SE suggests this one is related https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1856408/4997