# Show that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{14}]$ is not an Euclidean domain with regard to this norm.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, euclidean-domain

For every $a+b\sqrt{14}∈\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{14}]$ define the norm function by: $N(a+b\sqrt{14})=|a^2-14b^2|$

Show that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{14}]$ is not an Euclidean domain with regard to this norm.

**My Attempt**: By calculating $N(15+4\sqrt{14})=1$, we can see that $15+4\sqrt{14}\ $ is a unit in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{14}]$. Also it can be shown that $4+\sqrt{14}$ is a universal side divisor. (Because it divides $2$.) Yet I don't know how these facts can help for the proof we want.

By searching the web and finding this link: [Have I found an example of norm-Euclidean failure in $\mathbb Z [\sqrt{14}]$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1856408/have-i-found-an-example-of-norm-euclidean-failure-in-mathbb-z-sqrt14?rq=1), I saw that the pair $2, 1+\sqrt{14}$ can be used as a contradiction for $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{14}]$ being an Euclidean domain regarding this norm. But the proof uses the multiplicativity of norm in $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{14}]$ , which is not what the question necessarily wants.

So I wrote it down myself and tried to prove it this way: Suppose there exists $a,b,c,d∈\mathbb{Z}$ such that $2=(a+b\sqrt{14})(1+\sqrt{14})+c+d\sqrt{14}$ and $N(c+d\sqrt{14})<13=N(1+\sqrt{14})$

$2=(a+14b+c)+(a+b+d)\sqrt{14}⇒2=a+14b+c $ and $a+b+d=0$

But also we have:

$|c^2-14d^2|<13⇒|c^2-14d^2|=|c^2-14d^2|$(mod $13$)$=|c^2-d^2|=|(c-d)(c+d)|$

I don't know how to continue from hereon. I would really appreciate it if either someone could complete my proof or could prove it in some way or other that doesn't use the norm in $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{14}]$.

**Note**: I know that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{14}]$ ***is*** actually an Euclidean domain by using another function as norm.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1856408/have-i-found-an-example-of-norm-euclidean-failure-in-mathbb-z-sqrt14/1865435#     you can see

Comment: @Jaymaa That's the link I mentioned in the body of my question :) and I said this proof uses the norm in $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{14}]$ which I'm not looking for.

Comment: What is problem you are facing

Comment: @Jaymaa a proof without using norm calculations in $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{14}]$. Read the question please.

Comment: You just show that the so call norm function is not preserving the property  that $N(ab)>=N(a)$

Comment: @Jaymaa I didn't show anything. I'd be happy If you can do it.

Comment: Which is proved  by the author which  i gave you the link

Comment: @Jaymaa In the answer which is given in that link, a calculation is done. This calculation is done regarding a/b which is a quotient and not necessarily a/b is in Z or $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{14}]$. I can't be more clear about that.

Comment: [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1148364/what-is-the-euclidean-function-for-mathbbz-sqrt14) is also discussing the topic. Did you see it?

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1236551/for-what-pairs-of-numbers-does-the-norm-function-fail-as-a-euclidean-function-in?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: @DietrichBurde Yes but didn't help much.

Comment: Multiplicativity is a key property of norms. Maybe there's no proof that doesn't use it.